# How do I compare a raw time in Java to now?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare a raw time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030891/how-do-i-compare-a-raw-time-in-java)

For example suppose I have

```
String endTime = "16:30:45";
```

How would I determine whether right now is before this time?  I have tried

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
Date date = sdf.parse(endTime);
```

However date has year 1970 and so the comparisons fail

Comment: don't post the same question again. Update your original one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always do the inverse:

```
"16:30:45".compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))
```

Comment: beautifully short. And correct (if the OP were interested in TZ or daylight-savings-time, they should have specified those for the 16:30:45 string too).

Comment: I know. There's hardly anything I hate as much as the `java.util.Calendar` ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
//Parse the time from String using SimpleDateFormat and set it to cal, reset other fields

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(parsedTimeinDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2000);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE,1);    
//reset other fields for now calendar those aren't related to time
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    calNow .set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
    calNow .set(Calendar.YEAR,2000);
    calNow .set(Calendar.DATE,1);

//determine 
    cal.before(calNow);
```

Comment: @Lukas it will take default timezone. as OP doens't mentioned anything about TZ :)

Comment: Is this daylight-savings-time-safe?

Comment: Haha, yeah. "didn't mention". I keep tracking down these kinds of mistakes... ;-) But this probably works, as both times are equally shifted to january

Comment: @Lukas +1 nice tricky soln, but I doubt for 12 hr format, and I don't see mentioned things in your solution too ;)

Comment: In my latitude, no one uses the 12hr format. ;-)