# parsing dateTime on remote server

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have problem on one remote server. I have the code:

```
source.setDate("20150120");
source.setTime("080000");

Date date = DateTimeFormat.DATE.get().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).parseDateTime(source.getDate()).toDate();

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.getDefault());
final DateTime newDateTime = DateTimeFormat.TIME.get().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).parseDateTime(source.getTime());
dateTime = newDateTime.withDate(dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonthOfYear(), dateTime.getDayOfMonth());
```

The result is

```
date = Mon Jan 19 23:00:00 GMT+03:00 2015
dateTime = Tue Jan 20 7:00:00 GMT+03:00 2015
```

The problem is that it returns (time-one hour) then source time on one remote server. On my local server such error doesn't occur. So why this happens as I use DateTimeZone.getDefault() which should return localServer timeZone
So why result date = current date - one hour?

UPD1. 
DateTimeFormat is really an enum with values

```
public enum DateTimeFormat {
    TIME("HHmmss"),
    DATE("yyyyMMdd");

    private final DateTimeFormatter value;

    public DateTimeFormatter get() {
        return value;
    }
```

My goal to parse date and time on any server, with any timeZone to the same time and date.

so if I parse time 8:00 it should display 8:00 in all timeZones

For current example DateTimeZone.getDefault() is Europe/Moscow
And the one strange thing that on another server with same time/zone the same code give another result.

Is this code theoretically correct? Because I thing that there are some mistakes in configuration of server properties

Comment: [a] Too much code. Give a [simple example, minimal code], explicit input & output & expectation. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please revise your question. [b] This is almost certainly addressed by many hundreds of existing Questions and Answers on StackOverflow. Being one hour off is a sure sign of a time zone problem.

Comment: The question was modified to easier version

Comment: You don’t give us the source behind "source", you don't give us the Date object value produced by `source.getDate()`, and you don’t give us your default DateTimeZone. You apply a formatter that adjusts the time zone. And you do not explain the purpose/goal of this code. I cannot see how expected us to help with this.

Comment: Yet another problem with the Question: There is no `DateTimeFormat.DATE` nor `DateTimeFormat.TIME` in Joda-Time 2.7 [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) class.

Comment: Sorry for not full question, added UPD1

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6030891/642706) and many others. Please search StackOverflow before posting. You would have found hundreds of Questions and Answers that address your issues. You need to do some learning, as [the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28027231/642706) said. Want you want has nothing to do with servers. Search for "LocalTime", "Joda" (sic) and "java.time", and "zone". Tip: Avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that source is a standard java.util.Date, why are you simply toString'ing the dates? They will be formatted using the server's timezone even though you go through a lot of code doing stuff with timezones. I think you really should look into how datetime behaves in Java. For one, the method you're using (getDate()) has been deprecated for a long time (no pun intended)

Note that the date object is simply a wrapper around a long value that is the unix epoch value of some point in time. I can't really see what exactly you're trying to do but my feeling is that it can be a lot simpler. All the string operations seem largely unnecessary as far as I can tell. They are certainly not needed to attempt to change anything to the timezone of a Date object, because a Date simply doesn't have timezone information stored in it. Timezones only come into play when formatting a date to make it readable to a human or some other system that doesn't understand epoch values.

For in-depth reading I can recommend http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php which explains a great deal about how to work with date and time. The most important takeaway in this case is that the Date object itself is never in a certain timezone.

Comment: Thanks for useful link. I updated question with UPD1

Comment: It's hard to tell what is the exact problem, but honestly I don't like using default timezones of a server, because they almost never are relevant and because you run into problems like you have. In my opinion it shouldn't usually matter where a server is physically located, though of course there are situations/applications where it does matter. In the framework I develop we do all timezone operations using UTC ór a user-defined timezone that is not connected to the one the server is running on.

Comment: But if I have logic that should covert input time(ex. 12:00:00) on any server to same time(ex. 12:00:00) on any server, the approach with UTC and user-defined timezone can't be applied? + added UPD2

Comment: No that is true. But why would you want to convert an arbitrary time into another arbitrary time? The only common thing they have is that they are at 12:00 in SOME timezone, but that fact is almost always meaningless. There are valid cases for a requirement like this (such as always needing to kick off some event at a certain local time) but they are quite rare.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion and help. It will be good idea to introduce additional field TimeZone in input Class to convert it then in java code.

Actually there was nothing wrong with my code. The problem was with configuration of the server